# Is it better to create a class instance, or create an instance each time a method is called?

Tags: c#, performance

I am creating a converter for use in a Windows 8 XAML app (MVVM).  As you can see in the code below, the converter is used to convert a bool into one of two strings from a language resource file.
My question is, is it better to create one instance of `ResourceLoader` for the converter class or should I continue creating new instances each time the method is called?

```
class BooleanToBudgetYearStringConverter : IValueConverter
{
    private const string CALENDAR = "BudgetCycle_Calendar",
                        FISCAL = "BudgetCycle_Fiscal";

    private Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.ResourceLoader loader;

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        string entryName = (value is bool && (bool)value) ? CALENDAR : FISCAL;  //The name of the entry desired from the entry file.
        return new Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.ResourceLoader().GetString(entryName);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        return (value is string && (string)value == new Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.ResourceLoader().GetString(CALENDAR));
    }
}
```

I am specifically concerned about speed and memory use.

Comment: Are you sure you should be newing up ResourceLoader objects at all? It seems like [Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.ResourceLoader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.resources.resourceloader.aspx) has static methods on it for getting access to ResourceLoader objects in a singleton manner already. Have you tried using Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.ResourceLoader.GetForCurrentView().GetString(entryName) instead?

Comment: If the tools support it, neither: let the framework manage and provide instances as appropriate. Not only is this better for client code; it also supports encapsulation, performance, and testing. If not, consider the cost of instantiation (probably negligible) before picking the better choice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Use an Attribute

The class should be tagged with:

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(Boolean), typeof(String))]
```

If it's of the normal, old-school .NET variety (desktop, client profile, WP8). Windows store apps don't appear to have an analogous attribute in their .NET libraries, and thus this recommendation can be ignored when compiling such a program.

## Drop Type Checks

If the passed-in value is not of the expected type, you should not do your conversion; you should allow an exception to be thrown, so that you know an invalid binding has taken place (and you can go correct the offending code). This applies to both conversion and back-conversion.

## Explicit Back Conversion

Check for an explicit match -- don't default to returning "false" on a non-match with the CALENDAR string. Instead, check that the input string matches with the FISCAL string. Throw an exception if the input string matches neither acceptable string.

## Use a Singleton

The documentation for `Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.ResourceLoader` implies that the [default constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br206020.aspx) you're using should result in an object that is identical in function to the one available from the static `GetForCurrentView()` function. If not, then set up your own singleton pattern to ensure that you have at most one shared copy of the resource object around at any given time.

Comment: +1 nice answer. I think the converter will still work without the attribute, care to expand on what the role of the `ValueConversionAttribute` is?

Comment: @Mat'sMug It's a clear (and machine readable) declaration of intent, so nobody has to guess. From [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.valueconversionattribute.aspx), "When implementing the IValueConverter interface, it is a good practice to decorate the implementation with a ValueConversionAttribute attribute to indicate to development tools the data types involved in the conversion[...]." Now, as to what specific tools use it, and how they use it, I don't know. I would assume it helps prevent bogus bindings. :)

Comment: For some reason `System.Windows.Data` and hence `ValueConversion` is not available in my Windows 8.1 app.

Comment: @Trisped Well, that's confusing, because [IValueConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is in System.Windows.Data. Are you referencing the PresentationFramework assembly from your project? Can you provide the fully-qualified name of the IValueConverter you're deriving from?

Comment: @TravisSnoozy `Windows.UI.Xaml.Data.IValueConverter`.  My project is referencing ".NET for Windows Store apps" and "Windows" which are the only two things I can reference in this type of application (except for other solutions and third party dlls).

Comment: @Trisped Ah, right, _that_ little nightmare. It doesn't appear that they ported that attribute over to the new flavor of .NET libraries. My apologies; I didn't realize you meant Metro (er... "windows store") app when you said "Windows 8." It's even more confusing in that the (non-store-app) MSDN page says this attribute is supported in the Win8 phone, as well as in the client profile... so it's a mystery to me why it's dropped from the windows store app API. :/

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> private const string CALENDAR = "BudgetCycle_Calendar",
>                     FISCAL = "BudgetCycle_Fiscal";
> ```

Would be much prettier as two instructions:

```
private const string CALENDAR = "BudgetCycle_Calendar";
private const string FISCAL = "BudgetCycle_Fiscal";
```

---

> ```
> private Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.ResourceLoader loader;
> ```

Given `using Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources;`, the above declaration can be simplified to:

```
private ResourceLoader loader;
```

The variable is declared, but never assigned, and isn't used anywhere.

I'd take [@Travis' advice](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/47938/is-it-better-to-create-a-class-instance-or-create-an-instance-each-time-a-metho#comment84077_47938) and assign it like this:

```
private ResourceLoader loader = ResourceLoader.GetForCurrentView();
```

This greatly improves the readability of your `return` statements:

```
return loader.GetString(entryName);
```

and

```
return (value is string && value.ToString() == loader.GetString(CALENDAR));
```

<sub>(follow [@Travis' advice here too](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/47942/23788), about explicit back conversion / well, his entire answer actually)</sub>